# EF7, error when 'Select' after 'Include', "Parameter name: querySource"

Tags: entity-framework, linq, select, include

```
var emps = db.Employments
            .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.Position)
            .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.ProjectSkills).ThenInclude(x => x.Skill)
            .Include(x => x.Company)
            .Where(x => x.UserId == "42fc803f-af62-4b20-8e60-18d30707292d")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Start)
            .Select(
                x => new
                {
                    EmplId = x.Id,
                    Company = x.Company,
                    Desc = x.Desc,
                    StartDate = x.Start,
                    EndDate = x.End,
                    Projects = x.Projects
                }).ToList();

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            ContentType = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"),
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emps)
        };
```

Hi All smarters. 
I'm using MVC6 EF7 to retrieve data from mutilple tables. The code as above, I got an error below. I'm beginner of EF7. No idea about the Parameter name, 'querySource'.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: querySource
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QuerySourceExtensions.HasGeneratedItemName(IQuerySource querySource)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitEntityQueryable(Type elementType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.EntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, String callerName)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.RelinqExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.ReplaceClauseReferences(Expression expression, IQuerySource querySource, Boolean inProjection)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.SelectClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I've noticed that, when I move the "ToList" clause just after 'OrderByDescending' and before 'Select', it works but tremendously slow. I know the  SQL statement will be invoked at 'ToList' point. So, this definitely not a solution. Can somebody point me out where I was wrong? or give me an idea to solve this problem? My appreciate.

```
 var emps = db.Employments
            .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.Position)
            .Include(x => x.Projects).ThenInclude(x => x.ProjectSkills).ThenInclude(x => x.Skill)
            .Include(x => x.Company)
            .Where(x => x.UserId == "42fc803f-af62-4b20-8e60-18d30707292d")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Start).ToList()
            .Select(
                x => new
                {
                    EmplId = x.Id,
                    Company = x.Company,
                    Desc = x.Desc,
                    StartDate = x.Start,
                    EndDate = x.End,
                    Projects = x.Projects
                });
```

[Database diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPSx5.png)

Comment: You are wasting your time fighting EF7 bugs, which are normal - as you know, EF7 is not released yet.

Comment: @IvanStoev Why we can't try it when it is not released yet? He properly need help.

Comment: @NamPham I think you are missing the point. Of course you can try unreleased software if you wish, but that's on your own risk, and don't expect help if something is not working properly because that's normal for unreleased software. In this particular case, everything that OP is doing is correct, and the problem he's experiencing is originating from a bug(s) in the (again) unreleased software he's using.